# Is there a separate name for a genre/sub genre for more “ancient” fantasy

Tags: ancient-history

Not sure if this was the right stack exchange, but I decided to go with this one.
Sorry about the title (it’s pretty vague)
But my question is rather simple actually.
My story is set in a made up world, but the time period is an analogue of the BCEs (Roman republic, Mesopotamia, Egypt, etc.) so my question is, is there a sub genre name for this kind of fantasy fiction world? If not, I will make a name for it.
Thanks

Comment: Good question! But probably Writing would be the more appropriate forum (which is why I voted to close).  Generally speaking, I've seen *Alēthē diēgēmata* (True History) considered to be the first SF story, and Lucian wrote that 1800 years ago.  I'd say that, like the Conan stories, like Somtow's *The Aquilliad*, your story would be considered fantasy plain and simple.  Feel free to let us help you with your world!

Comment: Thanks! I’m glad there are people who are interested!

Comment: Well, that's what we're here for! You've got a whole forum full of respondents who are just champing at the bit to review & respond to your questions!

Comment: If you want a precise answer you'll have to be more specific about the story you're writing. But from what you've told us so far, I believe the closest sub genre is [Sword & Sandal](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SwordAndSandal). Though really as @elemtilas said, it would be perfectly fine to just refer to whatever you're writing as fantasy. By its nature fantasy is such an expansive and diverse genre so there isn't necessarily the need to pigeonhole your work.

Comment: It's *fantasy*. There are many excellent fantasy novels set in an environment different from the vaguely Late Middle Ages / Early Renaissance made popular by the *Song of Ice and Fire*; just for example, Ken Liu's *The Grace of Kings*. In cinematography, fantasy films set in ancient worlds somewhat similar to the classical civilizations are called "peplum" or "[sword-and-sandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword-and-sandal)". (And Babylon is *in* Mesopotamia.)

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask this question and it is appropriate for the question to be closed. However, you might want to start by evaluating the [Book Industry Study Group's BISAC Subject Headings](https://bisg.org/page/BISACEdition). With very rare exception, when a publisher submits a book to the "industry" (distributors, book stores, etc), it must be categorized using that list. You don't get to change it because, quite literally, your book is expected to displace books of the same categorization on a bookstore shelf. Don't be inventive, just use the closest match.

Comment: Ok, I will make up my own genre name for fun